# how to open a text file using filedialog.askopenfile in our python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    #function to open the file
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
    from tkinter import filedialog
    root = tk.Tk()
    textPad = ScrolledText(root)
        def open_command():
            file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rt',title='Select a file')
            if file != None:
                contents = file.read()
                textPad.insert('1.0',contents)
                file.close()
```

I want to know how do I insert the contents I have read onto my GUI which is not happening.

Comment: You won't read any contents unless you call `open_command`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed your scrolledtext in the GUI? I added a `pack()` and `open_command()` call, and your code worked for me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tk.Tk()
textPad = ScrolledText(root)
textPad.pack()


def open_command():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rt',title='Select a file')
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textPad.insert('1.0',contents)
        file.close()

open_command()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: i am getting the option to choose the file.But the file is not opening on the gui i created

Comment: You have run the exact code and open a .txt file? Added an image above of it working.